# Alerting an array's contents

Tags: c#

I've got a 2 dimensional array, and I want to display its contents in a message box with a table. I will use `MessageBox.Show()`. When I use it, it just gives me a syntax on the whole thing.

How do I put it in a message box and how can I make it into a table?

Random number in first row, square root in second.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

     double[,] numbersArray = {{4,2},
                               {64,8},
                               {81,9},
                               {24,4.8},
                               {9,3},
                               {100,10},
                               {43,6.5},
                               {8,2.8},
                               {45,6.7},
                               {16,4}};
```

Comment: it looks like you have a console app. Try switching to a windows forms project, and then MessageBox.Show will work !

Comment: "a syntax on the whole thing"?  Could you explain what you mean by that?  If you mean syntax error, please provide the details so someone can accurately help you.  Also, is this a Console application or a Windows Forms Application?  If it's a console application, you're not supposed to call MessageBox, you should use Console.WriteLine instead.

Comment: He's learning C# and SO, go easy on him.

Comment: You need to reference the `System.Windows.Forms` assembly, and need to add an appropriate `using` directive. Probably you want a WinForms application, but adding the reference to a console app should work in principle.

Comment: when I type "MessageBox.Show()" in visual studio 2010, a red line appears underneath the whole thing ("MessageBox.Show()") with an error in the error list that reads "The name 'MessageBox' does not exist in the current context."

Comment: Thanks for the message box part, what about the table?

Comment: And as for switching to a windows forms project. I/We havent worked on that in class yet, but ill try and figure it out.

@Thinking Sites Thanks for the understanding and post edits.

Comment: A simple ignorant question shouldent cause a blood bath of negative comments and down votes. It discourages new users. (just a tip)

Comment: Since you're 'in a class' this is homework and I don't think a MessageBox is the goal. Use a `for()` loop and `Console.WriteLine()` to display your table.

Comment: So just because im "in a class" everything I do including personal prodjects. counts as "homework"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through the stuff and make all the numbers 1 string or create your own alert box.